# Cant find angle between 2 vectors

Tags: vector, angle

Could someone help me solve this problem? How can I find the angle shown in picture? I think I need to find angle between 2 vectors but im really bad at geometry.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0RKh.png

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple geometry calculation and not programming.

Comment: have you tried to google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing your program in C++, then to calculating an angle between two vectors you can use the atan2 function, it is present in many programming languages.

You need to call atan2 giving it the two components of a single vector and then you make calculations this way:

Calculating for the first vector: `atan2(v1_y, v1_x)`
Calculating for the second vector: `atan2(v2_y, v2_x)`

Caution: 
If the value returned by atan2 is negative (as atan2 returns value from range (-pi;+pi]), then you need to add 2 * pi to the result for each of the vector.

Finally you subtract the values of the vectors and what you get is the angle. The angle will be either positive or negative, depending which atan2 value you subtract from which one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize both vectors and then perform a [**dot product**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

## Step 1: Vector normalization:

A normalized vector has a length of 1. To achieve this, you divide its coordinates by its length:

```
float d = 1 / sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);
normalizedX = X * d;
normalizedY = Y * d;
normalizedZ = Z * d;
```

Note: The length is inversed and then multiplied instead of divided in order to increase performance.

## Step 2: Dot product

After your normalized both vectors like in Step 1, you need to perform a dot product:

```
float angle = acos(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2 + z1 * z2);
```

The result is the cosine of the angle between the two vectors. After an `acos` you have your angle.